# unable to find valid certification path to requested target(openJDK8)

Tags: java, spring, security, cloud

How can I solve this problem?

I want to install `spring-cloud-cli v2.2.0`

My current setup in Windows 10:

- `spring-cli v2.2.0`
- `openjdk-1.8.0.242-1`

I tried this command:

```
$ spring install org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cli:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`
```

Result is:

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:450)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:317)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:330)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:237)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621)
        ... 65 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:445)
        ... 71 more

1 error
```

I check JCE in `jre\lib\security\java.security`

`crypto.policy=unlimited` is no comment.

Please help me!